# Can't load native library. CPU arch invalid for this build in marshmallow(6.0)

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded csipsimple and compile successfully. application is working fine on android version below lolipop (5.0) but while I run android APK in MARSHMALLOW (6.0), android app goes crashed and a give this toast as **"Can't load native library. CPU arch invalid for this build"**.

I am getting the below exception while I am running this:

> 02-09 18:11:51.236: E/SIP SRV(4758): RESET SETTINGS !!!! 02-09
>   18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758): We have a problem with the current
>   stack.... NOT YET Implemented 02-09 18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library:
>   reloc_library[1290]:   113 cannot locate '__aeabi_ldiv0'... 02-09
>   18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370) 08-05 18:11:53.979:
>   E/PjService(4758):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
>   02-09 18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):    at
>   com.csipsimple.pjsip.PjSipService.tryToLoadStack(PjSipService.java:151)
>   02-09 18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):    at
>   com.csipsimple.service.SipService.loadStack(SipService.java:1179)
>   02-09 18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):    at
>   com.csipsimple.service.SipService.onStart(SipService.java:1099) 02-09
>   18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):  at
>   android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:438) 02-09
>   18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2715)
>   02-09 18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:139) 02-09
>   18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1334)
>   02-09 18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-09
>   18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 02-09 18:11:53.979:
>   E/PjService(4758):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944) 02-09
>   18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-09
>   18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-09 18:11:53.979:
>   E/PjService(4758):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   02-09 18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 02-09
>   18:11:53.979: E/PjService(4758):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**could anyone help me to get rid of this.?**

Comment: Did you manage to make it work on marshmallow? I have the same problem and can't find any solutions.

Comment: Hi Vikas, did you get any solution on this? I am also getting same problem

Answer (score 0):

It means that your native libs missing some architecture specific builds specific to your device. E.g. in my project list of native libs looks like:

[image: Native libs]

You have to check availability of your native libararies against used architecture

Comment: But I have same structure as you given and also this application is running on below marshmallow (6.0) version.

Comment: still issue is same. can anyone help me to get rid of this. ?